# when should we use "being"

Tags: syntax

From an [article in *The Hindu*](http://www.thehindu.com/todays-paper/tp-national/tp-andhrapradesh/textile-park-coming-up-in-guntur/article6223378.ece):

> An Integrated Textile Park (ITP) being developed at Edlapadu on Guntur-Chennai National Highway is expected to give the much-needed fillip to textile industry in Andhra Pradesh.

I do not understand the structure of this sentence, specifically the "being" part. To my knowledge "being" should be used only for Present and Past Continuous. I've googled around, but nothing came up.

Answer (score 7):

A noun phrase can be modified by a following participial clause, i.e. a clause introduced by a participle.

Examples:

> A cat [climbing a tree] ...
>
> A cat [attacked by a dog] ...
>
> A man [smoking] ...
>
> A building [being demolished with a wrecker ball] ...

As you see, both present participles (*-ing*) and past participles (*-ed* and various other formations) can be used in this construction. The modifying clause does not contain a finite verb (such as *is*). None of my examples is a sentence, as they all lack a main verb: they are more complex noun phrases, which could serve as subject or object (or other roles).

So the structure of your example is

> [[An Integrated Textile Park (ITP)] [being developed at Edlapadu on Guntur-Chennai National Highway]] is expected to give the much-needed fillip to textile industry in Andhra Pradesh.

where the whole of the outer set of [ ] marks the subject. The verb in the participle is passive, so *being developed* as opposed to *developing* (which would be active).

Comment: Does this this mean that the Park has been already developed completely (its developing finished in the past) or it's still under development?

Comment: It means that it is still under development,  because that is what the present participle means. The past participle (eg _developed_, or _attacked_ in my second example) does not have that implication: the speaker is not concerned about whether the activity is still going on or not. _Being developed_ functions as a passive present participle.

Comment: I'll amplify my previous comment: a past participle here usually means that the activity is finished, but doesn't always. _Look at this picture of a cat attacked by a dog_ might show a fight going on, or might show a wounded cat after the attack. _Watch this video of a cat attacked by a dog_ almost certainly shows a fight.

Comment: Interesting examples.

Answer (score 1):

This *is* passive present continuous. The park has not finished development, it is being developed at the time of writing.

Comment: Why did not they put "Park **is** being developed..." then?

Comment: True, but only half of the answer. See my answer.

Comment: @RuslanGerasimov because that's not the point of the sentence. They're not saying it is being developed, they're saying the park _that is_ being developed 'is expected to give the much-needed fillip to textile industry in Andhra Pradesh.'

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that it's correct grammatically. It means that Park is developed, and instead of "Park was developed and is expected..." or "Park has been developed and is expected.." they used "Park being developed at...on...is expected..."

Comment: It is correct grammatically, but this answer does not address the point of the question.